# How to use variable of shell script in java program without passing it as argument

Tags: java, shell

I am calling a java program from shell script. Shell script contains one variable which needs to use in java program.

Shell Script:

```
for s in 0 1
do
javac -cp $CLASSPATH ./src/*.java
java -cp $CLASSPATH Test
done
```

Test.java

```
main() {
sValue = ...; // here I need to get value from shell
someMethod(sValue) {
. ... . 
}
}
```

shell script has variable s with value 0 and 1. I need to use this variable in java program Test.

In my program I am can't pass this value as argument as "java -cp $CLASSPATH Test $s". So please provide some other solution.

Answer (score 1):

Propably (depends on shell) you will export the `s` variable to make it visible to the java process:

```
for s in 0 1
do
export V=$s
javac -cp $CLASSPATH ./src/*.java
java -cp $CLASSPATH Test
done
```

And then `System.getenv("V")` in Test.java.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is [System.getEnv(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv%28java.lang.String%29).